# Using Dispatch queue in swift 3 perfect 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, server, dispatch, perfect

I'm using swift perfect 2.0 and i need to call a function after 10 seconds. I can make it work on a normal iOS application with this code:

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 10
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when){
    //call function
}
```

But i can't do this in swift perfect, and i don't know how to work arround. This is the structure of my request:

```
public func InsertPost(_ request: HTTPRequest, response: HTTPResponse)

    //logic

    response.status = .custom(code: 200, message: "Success!")
    response.completed()

    //here i want to send a notification to some users, but only after 10 seconds. 
    //So i try to call function sendNotifications() like this:

    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 10
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when){
        sendNotifications()
    }
{
```

It never calls sendNotifications(), even if i place it before response.completed(), and i'm probably thinking wrong. So my question is, is there any other way to use Dispatchqueues in perfect 2.0? They don't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now i understand. I can't block main queue in swift perfect.

solution:

```
let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.app.queue", qos: .background, target: nil)

let when = DispatchTime.now() + 10
backgroundQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: when){
    //call function
}
```

Comment: Looks like we shouldn't use the main queue. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

It looks like perfect 2.0 has it's own thread management setup. Checkout this link:

http://perfect.org/docs/thread.html